# How to get most recent gmail message in a thread using python

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I am working on a python/django script where I need to parse out the most recent message from the body of a gmail email thread. I am using the "django-mailbox" app (https://github.com/latestrevision/django-mailbox) which imaps into my gmail account and puts the emails into a sqllite table:

```
CREATE TABLE "django_mailbox_message" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "mailbox_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "django_mailbox_mailbox" ("id"),
    "subject" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "message_id" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "in_reply_to_id" integer,
    "from_header" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "to_header" text NOT NULL,
    "outgoing" bool NOT NULL,
    "body" text NOT NULL,
    "encoded" bool NOT NULL,
    "processed" datetime NOT NULL,
    "read" datetime
)
```

I have trying to test this by just grabbing the first email containing a "Re:.." in the subject using the following django view:

```
def hello(request):
    from django_mailbox.models import Message
    import base64
    qs = Message.objects.filter(subject__contains="Re:")    

    if qs.count() > 0:
        first = qs[0]  // grab the first gmail message with subject containing Re:
    else:
        output = "empty"    

    newline = base64.b64decode(first.body)    

    return HttpResponse(newline)
```

This all works but the decoded body of the message is very difficult to decipher with a mixture of header info and actual message text. Is there further processing which could be done first to make the individual messages a little easier to separate. I'm just interested in grabbing the most recent message in a thread.